# Combining eol characters with placeholders

Tags: python, printing, python-3.x

I have to loop through some numbers in an array and output them nicely formatted. How can I combine the end of line character with a placeholder?

I have this:

```
for i in range(0,4):
    print("%.2f", end="\t" % (div1Data[i]))
```

But I get an error saying:

```
not all arguments converted during string formatting div1Data does contain floats.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is no placeholder `%s` in the `\t` string. Also, what is `div1Data`?

Comment: `print("%.2f" % div1Data[i], end="\t")` ??

Comment: div1Data is an array of floats

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you're actually trying to format the string passed to `end` i.e `'\t'`, which is raising that error. You should do something like this:

```
for i in range(0,4):
    print("%.2f" % div1Data[i], end='\t')
```

**Error:**

```
>>> '\t' % 1.001
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-77-8e0f35262786>", line 1, in <module>
    '\t' % 1.001
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```